# How can I create a URL for a specific cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am a teacher who is trying to create QR codes for book reviews to be placed on books in the library. I have collected all of my students' book reviews via a Google Form, so that their answers are on a Google Sheets (one column, about 100 rows). Instead of creating a QR code from the reviews and limiting the characters for the length, I'd rather have each review be a separate URL and use that address to create the QR code instead. Instead of creating 100+ different web pages or sheets in Google, if there was a way to create a link directly to a specific cell in the sheet that would be incredibly helpful.

I tried to use the query formula (limit and offset) after publishing the web page and also not publishing it, but I get an error each time.
I tried adding the range/cell using this URL: https://docs.google.com/a/apsva.us/spreadsheets/d/1agxRLfypqjknOHPGPq_zRqJNvSRso-0b8XOH3P67a1E/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&range=A1

but it comes up with the error page saying:

> Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.
>
> Please check the address and try again.

I'm not sure if I typed it in wrong or what.

The code I used originally was: `/gviz/tq?tq=limit 1 offset 32`

It actually is working today to give me the limited row, but there are a lot of extraneous characters included (this is the actual link: https://docs.google.com/a/apsva.us/spreadsheets/d/1agxRLfypqjknOHPGPq_zRqJNvSRso-0b8XOH3P67a1E/gviz/tq?tq=limit%201%20offset%2032)

[image: Screen Shot of above URL]

Is there a way (or an easier way) to do this?

Is there any way to keep the formatting of the Google Sheet?

Comment: Hi Rachael and welcome on Web Applications !! Would you care to share the formula with us and the error message, so that we can have a better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: @Rachel The URLs aren't to public files. Consider to create a demo of what you are trying without any sensitive data and share it with only with who has the link or public with the web or add screenshots.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I didn't think about the privacy settings when using Google Apps through my school account. I've included a screen shot for the second link above, but won't be able to create a public copy of the document until I can access my home computer later tonight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Query Language will return a [JSON string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example). To get the cell value and format as you see in the spreadsheet,  instead of `/gviz/tq?tq=` and the query string, use `/pubhtml?gid=` and the "right" parameters.

The easiest way is to get the URL resulted of publishing the spreadsheet to the web. Then...

Add `range=A1` to the URL of the published spreadsheet, where `A1` is the cell that you want to display.

I.E. for  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NIIqpRSYCXT0OlvDgXa0g4GVxmrnvQOSn_L-HcgPqVA/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

to display only the cell `B13`, the resulting URL is:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NIIqpRSYCXT0OlvDgXa0g4GVxmrnvQOSn_L-HcgPqVA/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&range=B13

to remove the header, add `chrome=false`:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NIIqpRSYCXT0OlvDgXa0g4GVxmrnvQOSn_L-HcgPqVA/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&range=B13&chrome=false

Note:
Use `?` before the first parameter.
Use `&` when adding the second and subsequent parameters.

**References**
[Publish a document, spreadsheet, presentation, or drawing - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en)
[Cómo publicar en Web un rango - Ejemplos para los foros](https://sites.google.com/site/ejemplosparaforos/blog/comopublicarenwebunrango) (How to publish a range in the Web - Examples for forums, self citation)